# Spring Data JPA: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit4

I am trying to add crossOrigin variable in `Application.property` file.  and accessing that variable through controller using `@value` its working for following two end point's but when I am adding @value to third end point I am getting following error message

**AccountController.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api.spacestudy.com/SpaceStudy/Admin/Account")
public class AccountController {

    @Autowired
    AccountService accService;

    @Value("${crossOrigin}")
    @GetMapping("/loadAcctLocationList")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Account>> findLocation() {
        return  ResponseEntity.ok(accService.findLocation());
    }

}
```

**TestAccountController**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class TestAccountController {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Mock
    private AccountService accountService;

    @InjectMocks
    private AccountController accountController;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(accountController).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void findLocationTest() throws Exception {

        Account account = new Account();
        account.setsLocation("Test1");

        List<Account> accountObj = new ArrayList<Account>();
        accountObj.add(account);    

        Mockito.when(accountService.findLocation()).thenReturn(accountObj);

        mockMvc.perform(get("/spacestudy/$ InstituteIdentifier/admin/account/loadAcctLocationList"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].sLocation", is("Test1")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.*",Matchers.hasSize(1)));    

        for(Account result: accountObj) {

            assertEquals("Test1", result.sLocation);

        }

        }
```

**application.properties**

```
crossOrigin =@CrossOrigin(origins ="http://localhost:4200")
server.port=8086
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/SpaceStudyDB
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
```

**Console**

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-05-15 01:59:17.915 ERROR 5240 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'accountController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'btnSaveClick' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.spacestudy.model.AccountMaintenanceSave'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.spacestudy.model.AccountMaintenanceSave': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:667) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at com.spacestudy.SpaceStudyAdminAccountMaintenance.main(SpaceStudyAdminAccountMaintenance.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.spacestudy.model.AccountMaintenanceSave'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.spacestudy.model.AccountMaintenanceSave': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.doConvert(TypeConverterSupport.java:74) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterSupport.java:47) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1093) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.spacestudy.model.AccountMaintenanceSave': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:307) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:109) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.doConvert(TypeConverterSupport.java:64) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
```

Can any one tell me what I am doing wrong in above code ? or tell me any another way to declare variable in application.property file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like what Spring is trying to do here is inject the value of `${crossOrigin}` into your method.

1. In `findLocation`, it's not breaking because there are no method arguments in which to inject the value
2. In the `btnSearchClick`, there's more than one argument and it's not attempting to inject the value
3. There's one argument, and it's trying to inject the value of `${crossOrigin}` into `AccountMaintenanceSave saveObj`

You should just inject `${crossOrigin}` into a `@CrossOrigin` at the top of your class? Like so:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "${crossOrigin}")
@RequestMapping("/api.spacestudy.com/SpaceStudy/Admin/Account")
public class AccountController {

    @Autowired
    AccountService accService;

    ...
}
```

And access the variable that way. You'll need to remove the `@Value` annotations from your controller methods.

You'll also need to just specify the origin name in your `application.properties`:

```
crossOrigin=http://localhost:4200
```

Comment: what I need to declare on method

Comment: I guess you don't programmatically need the value of crossOrigin, you just need CORS enabled on your controller. You can do that with the class-level `@CrossOrigin` annotation

Comment: now i checked when I added cross origin like above I am getting test case failure  error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'crossOrigin' in value "${crossOrigin}"`

Comment: can you tell why this happen at the time of test case running. when I comment `@CrossOrigin` test cases running properly

Comment: Make sure you have included the `crossOrigin` property to your test context when you run the test

Comment: We can move the discussion there since it's a new issue

Comment: Could not resolve placeholder problem didn't solved. can you tell me where and how  i need to add cross origin in test